# Setting Apache header with conditions of excluding paths/directorys / server ips

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I use a WordPress plugin called Duplicator Pro and the best way of installing with their installers is to use the servers IP rather than the domain because that way it autofills & conects to the server easier, while also not triggering multiple ModSecurity rules.

The best installation URL is:

`http://111.222.333.444/~customcpanelaccount/customfolder/installer.php`

Instead of:

`https://website.com/customfolder/installer.php`

If you load either of those files it automatically redirects you to:

`/customfolder/dup-installer/main.installer.php`

However because the server has the following Apache/LiteSpeed rule, it automatically redirects the http:// to https:// which causes it to throw up the following message:

[image: Connect to Network]

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
</IfModule>
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to make the above Apache/LiteSpeed rule to only apply to domains, not direct IPs OR to make it so it doesn't trigger when using the file of `installer.php`, `main.installer.php` and the directory of `/dup-installer/`

It's a shame there is no FilesNotMatch / DirectoryNotMatch / LocationNotMatch type if statements.

Any one have any ideas, I would greatly appreciate the help/advice!

Answer (score 0):

You could set an environment variable (eg. `DOMAIN_REQUESTED`) if a domain is requested (as opposed to the IP address) and set the `Header` conditionally based on whether this env var is set by using the `env=` argument.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Host "[a-z]" DOMAIN_REQUESTED
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;" env=DOMAIN_REQUESTED
```

If the `Host` header contains a character a-z then you must be requesting a domain name, not the IP address. In which case the `DOMAIN_REQUESTED` env var is set to `1`.

However...

- It seems odd that it would be preferable to install this over insecure HTTP using the server's IP address and a per-user web directory?! Per-user web directories (mod_userdir) are generally best avoided as it really messes with root-relative URL-paths.
- If this is only for the installation process, can you not simply comment out that `Header` directive temporarily?

> It's a shame there is no FilesNotMatch / DirectoryNotMatch / LocationNotMatch type if statements.

Well, there kind-of is, as you can use a *negative-lookahead* (or *lookbehind*) in the regex to determine when a match does *not* occur.

> ...OR to make it so it doesn't trigger when using the file of `installer.php`, `main.installer.php` and the directory of `/dup-installer/`

The `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;` HTTP response header only affects linked assets, not the top-level navigation. So this doesn't apply to `installer.php` and `main.installer.php` anyway. If these requests are being *upgraded* (or, more likely "redirected") then something else is doing that.